# How do I show only categories with unread items in the Feedly sidebar?

Tags: feedly

Because of the announced shutdown of Google Reader, I'm giving Feedly a try. It seems okay, but one thing that really pains me after linking it to Reader is that lots of categories are showing even if they have no unread items in them. 
In Google Reader, I had over a 100 categories, but I set it to only display the ones that had unread items in them.

Feedly shows all of these categories in non-alphabetical order, which feels extremely cluttered. Is there some way to fix this?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!

In *Preferences | General*, find "Filter Empty Collections" and set it to "On".

[image: "Filter Empty Collections" option]

Comment: Huh, it even defaulted to on, yet I never noticed the change. Thanks for your update!

Comment: I have no idea when they added it, but it's been that way for several years.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible yet, but I would love to be proven wrong.

Comment: Care to expand on this?

Comment: Given the amount of votes for [this uservoice suggestion](http://feedly.uservoice.com/forums/192636-suggestions/suggestions/3744372-hide-folders-that-have-0-unread-items) I'm inclined to believe you. It's funny, most of the feature requests there are somehow aimed at making feedly more like Reader.

Comment: It was true back then, but some time in the intervening years they added it.